# Generate a code like "50VIABC001" and if the value "ABC" appear again than append "002", "003" and so on..?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, data-binding

I have a grid with many names when the user clicks on any name it binds the details of that name to textboxes, dropdown etc.,

In this I have a textbox which generates code for that name.

I'm generating a code something like this. First 4 digits "50VI" will remain same for all followed by 1 letter from each 'firstName', 'MiddleName' and 'LastName'. Finally, it should have 3 digit number starting from '001', '002' and so on.

This final 3 digit should be decided on the 3 letters from First middle and last names.

Example: 50VI**FMS**001 where F=**F**irstName M=**M**iddleName S=**S**irName..
If another person has similar name format then the code should be "50VIFMS002" and so on.

I have written the code in Vb.NET but now the value that I get is "50VIFMS000" where "000" is same everywhere. So I'm stuck with last 3 digit part.

```
Public Function GenNewCode()

    Dim code As String = "50VI" & String.Concat(txtFName.Text.Trim, 
          txtMName.Text.Trim, txtLName.Text.Trim).ToUpper().Substring(0, 3)

    Dim exec As New ExecuteQuery

    Dim CNT As String = exec.ExecuteScalar("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ADMDOCTMST WHERE DOCTCODE LIKE '" & code & "%'")

    txtNewCode.Text = code & CNT.PadLeft(2, "0")

    Return code

End Function
```

Comment: Have you debugged and checked what you got at `Dim CNT as string = ...`?

Comment: Hi Dhaval, i get "0" in Dim CNT as string .. and "50VIABH00" in txtNewCode.text

Comment: I guess my code is not proper..In case of Name like this FirstName = A. MiddleName = "" (Empty) and lastName = C It gives code like this "50VIA.C".. it take ''." and even " " (Space) too. please help with this also.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, turn on Option Strict.

```
Public Function GenNewCode()
```

Functions have a return type.

```
Dim code As String = "50VI" & String.Concat(txtFName.Text.Trim,  txtMName.Text.Trim, txtLName.Text.Trim).ToUpper().Substring(0, 3)
```

Check your parenthesis. The .ToUpper and .Substring are acting on the concatenated string; not each string individually so you are gettin the first three characters in the first name.

```
txtNewCode.Text = code & CNT.PadLeft(2, "0")
```

You are starting your sequence at 001, so if your query returns a count of 3. That would be 001, 002, 003. You need to increment the count to get a new value. Also, .PadLeft will only work up to 9. Check the length of the incremented value then pad accordingly.

```
Return code
```

You haven't changed the value of code since your original Dim code so you will not get the value you are expecting. Setting code & ... to a text box does not change the value of code.

```
Public Function GenNewCode() As String
        Dim FName As String = "Mary"
        Dim MName As String = "ruth"
        Dim LName As String = "Smith"
        Dim FInitial As String = FName.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper
        Dim MInitial As String = MName.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper
        Dim LInitial As String = LName.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper
        Dim code As String = "50VI" & FInitial & MInitial & LInitial
        Dim exec As New ExecuteQuery
        Dim CNT As Integer = CInt(exec.ExecuteScalar("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ADMDOCTMST WHERE DOCTCODE LIKE '" & code & "%'"))
        CNT += 1
        Dim cntStr As String = CStr(CNT)
        Dim Padding As Integer = 3 - cntStr.Length 'You want a total length of 3 so subtract existing length from 3
        code &= cntStr.PadLeft(Padding, CChar("0"))
        Return code
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mary...It worked :-) Have a nice day. God bless